# I want to reset user's post meta after successfully login

Tags: plugins

I want to reset admin's meta value after login. It can be changed after login by admin via control panel, but I want to reset it after every login.

I used this code but it's not working:

```
function reset_dismiss_message(){
    update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'tgmpa_dismissed_notice', false );
}
add_action('wp_login', 'reset_dismiss_message');
```

I checked if and found it that the **get_current_user_id()** function is not returning user's ID as there is no data generated when wp_login action processing.

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_login` action [passes](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/user.php#L64) 2 arguments `$user_login` and `$user`. The second argument is the object of `WP_User` class, which you can use to get user id from:

```
function reset_dismiss_message( $user_login, $user ) {
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'tgmpa_dismissed_notice', false );
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'reset_dismiss_message', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead you might want to try;

```
function reset_dismiss_message(){
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'tgmpa_dismissed_notice', false );
}
add_action('wp_login', 'reset_dismiss_message');
```

Comment: don't mix up `wp_login` function with `wp_login` action ;)

Comment: @EugeneManuilov I thought as much... was just going by vague memory. Removed, thanks.